# REST::Client giving error 500 Not a SCALAR reference

Tags: perl, rest, rest-client

I am new to REST::Client module.
i made a script which will call an API through above module.

below is my script:

```
use REST::Client;
use Data::Dumper;

my $client = REST::Client->new();

my $resp = $client->request(
    'POST',
    "https://api.icims.com/customers/{ID}/search/people",
    {
        'Connection' => 'close',
        'Link'       => 'https://api.icims.com/customers/{ID}/people/;rel="person";
    title="Person Profile"',
        'Content-Length'   => '280',
        'Content-Type'     => 'application/json',
        'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip',
        'Host'             => 'api.icims.com',
        'User-Agent'       => 'Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 (java 1.5)',
        'Accept-Encoding'  => 'gzip,deflate',
        Accept             => 'application/json'
    }
);

print Dumper($resp->{_res}->{_content});
```

and this is printing below response:

```
$VAR1 = '500 Not a SCALAR reference';
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you put `{ID}` in there, or is there a real ID in your program? If it's like that, how should it know the ID?

Comment: `Accept             => 'application/json'` should be `'Accept'             => 'application/json'`?

Comment: @simbabque my mistake, thanks

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere is a nice debugging aid for this kind of problem.

Comment: @simbabque there is real ID in my program.

Comment: @simbabque, thanks for recommending "metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere"  but it is not already installed and i can not install it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the *body* of your request. [A POST request with REST::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client#POST-(-$url,-%5B$body_content,-%25$headers%5D-)) is supposed to have the body first, and then the optional headers.

> POST ( $url, [$body_content, %$headers] )
>
> Preform an HTTP POST to the resource specified. Takes an optional body content and hashref of custom request headers.

Since you don't seem to have a body, just use `undef`.

```
my $resp = $client->request(
    'POST',
    "https://api.icims.com/customers/{ID}/search/people",
    undef,                                              # here
    {
        'Connection' => 'close',
        'Link'       => 'https://api.icims.com/customers/{ID}/people/;rel="person";title="Person Profile"',
        'Content-Length'   => '280',
        'Content-Type'     => 'application/json',
        'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip',
        'Host'             => 'api.icims.com',
        'User-Agent'       => 'Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 (java 1.5)',
        'Accept-Encoding'  => 'gzip,deflate',
        Accept             => 'application/json'
    }
);
```

It's probably nicer to use the `POST` method. It's easier to read.

```
my $resp = $client->POST(
    "https://api.icims.com/customers/ID/search/people",
    undef,
    { ... }
);
```

Comment: thanks for replying.
I tried with GET method also which doesn't require any body to pass.
Still i am getting same error.

Comment: @Aj06 it works for me. It does give me an erroneous response obviously, because the ID is wrong, but the error you describe is not happening.